# how to put array contents into a variable

Tags: php

I want to know how to put the content inside an array into a variable for example:

in my array $result i have this

```
[0] =>  One
[1] =>  Two
[2] =>  Three
```

What i now want to do is to save this order into a variable. Can anyone help with the coding?

EDIT:

What i mean is i want to save the order ONE, TWO, THREE

Then i want to creata another order as TWO, ONE, THREE

Comment: What do you mean by save the *order*?

Comment: what exactly are you expecting the output to be?  comma delimited?  Or just like "OneTwoThree"?  Please clarify your expectations.

Comment: Your question is very basic - the answer is that you are already looking at the variable `$result`.  You can simply copy that into another variable like this `$newVariable = $result` or simply keep using that same variable.

Comment: Wait, do you mean you have literally the string representation of an array like `Array ( [0] => One... )` and you want to convert that to a real array?

Comment: Is there any logic to this order that you want to change?  Is it simply a manual change?  Perhaps you can give us some context - where in your code are you using this and what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Basically i am trying to get the list from a html file, and put that list inside an array, but i want to use mysql and change the order of the list depending on the mysql data which can be anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell if you want to save the content or the key into a string, in the case of the content, use something like this:

```
<?php
$var = implode(",", $result);
?>
```

if on the other hand you want the keys, try this:

```
<?php
$res = array_keys($result);
$var = implode(",", $res);
?>
```

Comment: It's not a very constructive question.  Please don't encourage these questions :)

Comment: Actually i agree its not a good question I am confused with my code Sorry